# How to determine if an image is previewable in current browser with Fine-Uploader?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

The goal is to generate thumbnails/previews server-side **only** if it cannot be done client-side.

The [Fine-Uploader documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/thumbnails.html) states:

> However, you should take care to not blindly return a `thumbnailUrl` for
>   images that are already previewable in modern browsers unless your
>   server intends to orient them correctly first.

How does the server know if Fine-Uploader is able to generate the preview client-side or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to reliably determine if a specific preview has generated successfully *before* the file upload request has been sent, as preview generation is an asynchronous process and may complete after the request has been sent. However, you *can* determine if the current browser has the ability to generate image preview by checking the `imagePreviews` [feature flag](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/browser-support.html#feature-flags). If `qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews` is `true`, then the current browser is capable of generating client-side image previews. If this flag is `false` you can set a [parameter with all upload requests](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request.params) that instructs your server to return an image preview URL instead. For example, you can setup your params option to do this:

```
request: {
   params: isBrowserPreviewPossible: qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews
}
```

The `isBrowserPreviewPossible` param w/ value will be sent with every upload request to your server. This is [demonstrated in the live S3 uploader at FineUploader.com](http://fineuploader.com/demos.html#amazon-demo).

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for the response. I would really like to make this possible. I've found `isPreviewable()` function in your code. Can you tell how reliable it is? Is it certain that a browser will generate the preview if that function returns success?

Comment: You certainly could use that, and it _is_ reliable, since Fine Uploader uses it internally. The check is asynchronous, so you'll need to handle the promissory return type. You'll need to check before the file is uploaded (set `autoUpload` to `false` or grab the file from some other means before passing it to Fine Uploader. Once you have the `File`/`Blob`: `var identifier = new qq.Identify(file, function(){}); var promise = identifier.isPreviewable;`. Fine Uploader uses the [non-standard `qq.Promise` internally](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/async-tasks-and-promises.html).